# Impersonating in .NET using Process.Start and UAC

Tags: windows-server-2008, uac, elevation, process-elevation

I am trying to run programs from another .NET program that requires elevation using the impersonation option of the Process.Start (System.Diagnostics) method. The user for impersonation is a local administrator.  The O/S is 2008 and UAC is turned on.
Whenever calling process start I'm getting a Win32 permission error:

"The requested operation requires elevation"

Answer (score 5):

If the .NET application you are calling is configured properly in the app.manifest, you don't have to specify anything in the Process.Start call - the UAC will appear automatically.

app.manifest setting:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: make sure `UseShellExecute` is true.

Comment: The default value for UseShellExecute is actually true. But good point anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Some information you might find helpful:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately both links were not helpful. From what I've read so far it seems that as part of the UAC it is not possible to open a process with impersonation and also run it elevated at the same time.